# Use union type variable in an async pipe with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, async-pipe

My template contains an async pipe for input binding with a union type variable :

`<app-mycomponent *ngSwitchCase="'myType'" [target]="myVar| async"></app-mycomponent>`

myVar is either Observable or string as a type.

`@Input() myVar!: Observable<blabla>[]> | string;`

But I get this error :

> Argument of type 'string | Observable<blabla[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<blabla[]> | Subscribable<blabla[]> | Promise<blabla[]>'.

How can I cast my variable to pass the async pipe ?

Comment: Please post complete code and not just fragments. There's not enough here to answer the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I agree with Maqggini; while your error does provide you with enough information to solve this problem, it is missing vital detail(s). This error could be generated from an attempt to assign a value somewhere, and not related to the markup/template at all. There is not enough detail to properly answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can't. But in such case we can create inner Observable.

```js
@Input() set myVar(value: Observable<blabla[]> | string) {
  this.innerVar = typeof value === 'string' ? of(string) : value;
}
```

```html
<app-mycomponent [target]="innerVar| async"></app-mycomponent>
```

Comment: I would like to keep the string out of an observable if possible by filtering with ngIf or something but it seems to be the only solution atm. Thanks.